# How to get the count of the DIVs with almost the same ID property?

Tags: javascript

I have many DIVs on my page with the same ID

eg:

```
<div id="myDiv1">
   ...
</div>
<div id="myDiv2">
   ...
</div>
<div id="myDiv3">
   ...
</div>

...

<div id="myDiv20">
   ...
</div>

...
```

As You see, the ID property looks almost the same - the only diffrence is that there is a number in each ID.

How to get the count of that DIVs? I thought I can do something like that:

```
var myDivs= document.getElementById('myDiv');
```

but returns null

Comment: And more importantly, why do you need this information for? And would you be able to get the same information without relying on the id attribute?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) like this:

```
$('div[id^=myDiv]')
```

If you can't use jQuery, you'll need to call `getElementsByTagName` and loop through the values checking the ID property.

Comment: You might consider updating the jQuery link to point to the selectors page, since that's the most relevant page to the question. (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 4):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var counter = 0;
for(var i in divs) {
    if(divs[i].id.indexOf('myDiv') === 0) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

or just

```
document.querySelectorAll('[id^=myDiv]').length
```

Comment: it works, but if another myDiv is added, the 'counter' has still the same value. The code seems not to see the dynamically added myDiv

Comment: Put all of the code in a function and run the function before & after adding another div, it should work.

Comment: When I use this, I'm getting twice as many in Chrome as I do in Firefox. Any idea why?

Comment: Insert `console.log(divs[i]);` inside the if-case and hover the result in your console for a quick review of the result. You can try the edited (second) suggestion as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery

```
//this will give you all divs start with myDiv in the id 
var divs = $("div[id^='myDiv']");
```

Comment: You shouldn't use an `@` sign.

Answer (score 0):

From [this site](http://www.ab-d.fr/date/2008-12-14/):

```
function getElementsByRegExpId(p_regexp, p_element, p_tagName) {
        p_element = p_element === undefined ? document : p_element;
        p_tagName = p_tagName === undefined ? '*' : p_tagName;
        var v_return = [];
        var v_inc = 0;
        for(var v_i = 0, v_il = p_element.getElementsByTagName(p_tagName).length; v_i < v_il; v_i++) {
            if(p_element.getElementsByTagName(p_tagName).item(v_i).id && p_element.getElementsByTagName(p_tagName).item(v_i).id.match(p_regexp)) {
                v_return[v_inc] = p_element.getElementsByTagName(p_tagName).item(v_i);
                v_inc++;
            }
        }
        return v_return;
    }
```

Usage:

```
var v_array = getElementsByRegExpId(/^myDiv[0-9]{1,2}/);
```